# Should i use one table or more than one table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am having two tables `pages(id,name)` and `posts(id,msg)`
In both `pages` and `posts` having `id` field which is  auto incremented and starts from 1

I want to create  like table when a user likes a `post` or `page` details should be stored in like table.

My question is  should i use different like table for `post` and `pages`

```
  1) page_like(page_id,user_id);// (page_id,user_id) composite PK
   2) post_like(post_id,user_id);//(post_id,user_id) composite PK
```

or should i use

```
 like(element_id,element_type,liked_by) //(element_id,element_type,liked_by) composite PK
```

Which method should i use and why ?
Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the choices presented, you should definitely go with the first one. The alternative prevents you from declaring a FOREIGN KEY, and enforcing referential integrity in the application code is [surprisingly difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20873843/533120).

That being said, there is a third option: "inherit" both `post` and `page` from a common "super-table", then like the super-table directly. This is probably not justified for just two sub-types, but can be very useful if you anticipate your model will grow in the future. I have described the basic idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8113064/533120).

Answer (score 0):

If you have two distinct keys that automatically increment individually for page and post, I would definitely use two separate tables.  It wouldn't make sense for you two have a row that has a post and a page with two sets of distinct keys.

Comment: What are the problems with second table type