# Is it possible to have an dynamic foreign key, and what is the best/correct to do so?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

For example:
I have a "history" table with a foreign key that might point to different tables/entities depending a field value.

Table history:

```
create table history(
    id int PimaryKey AUTO_INC,
    elementid int, (ForeignKey)
    elementtype varchar
)
```

this table is populated for example:

```
id               ElementId           ElementType
1                1                   Device
2                2                   Simcard
3                2                   Simcard
```

this tells we have

- 1 record for entity of type "Device" with id "1"
- 2 records for entity of type "Simcard" with id "2"

the goal is to have a table that might be used for multiple entities.

Is this the correct way to integrate an dynamic foreign key?
What I also thought of was for creating an list with tables/entities to refer to
So the table then would look like:

```
ALTER TABLE history MODIFY ElementType INTEGER;
```

ElementType would refer to:

```
create table entities(
    id int PimaryKey AUTO_INC,
    name varchar
)
```

the new table history is populated for example:

```
id               ElementId           ElementType
1                1                   1
2                2                   2
3                2                   2
```

The entities table is populated for example:

```
id               name
1                Device
2                Simcard
```

Comment: Is it a coincidence that the `elementid` of 2 equals a simcard? Reason I ask is that if that would always be the case, the `elementid` would already identify the element as a simcard, and thus the `elementtype` column would be redundant.

Comment: @SchmitzIT no. The elementId refers to the record id of the entity that is filled in elementType. For example I have an entity simcard with a couple instances/rows I want to have record id 3 of entity simcard, so this wil be an instance of history with: elementid = 3 elementType= simcard
ElementType refers to the entity

Answer (score 14):

The proper way to implement dynamic FKs is to not do it.

Here are the [reasons why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20873843/533120), and what to [do instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317463/533120).