# Crows Foot Notation in MySQL Workbench

Tags: database-design, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to model a list of emails in Crows Foot notation using MySQL Workbench 5.2. The design wants me to indicate that the Email table must link to one of two other tables, SenderInContacts or SenderNotInContacts. How do I show that in crows foot notation using MySQL workbench?

Comment: You shouldn't use "dynamic" (aka. "generic" or "polymorphic") FKs. Use exclusive "static" FKs or inheritance instead. More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22377168/533120).

Answer (score 0):

Two points here:

1. Always use the latest version of MySQL Workbench for great new features and lots of bug fixes.
2. If you are talking about a required relationship then have a look at the `mandatory` field in the relationship editor (double click the relationship to open it).

Btw. The object notation has nothing to do with the various cardinality or mandatory settings.