# Is this a good idea to store relations to many different tables in one field?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I have 4 basic models which are stored in following tables:

- users
- images
- videos
- posts

In application logic user may "love" `image` or `url` or `post` (for example user clicks little heart next to image or video etc). So I have to keep all "loves" in database. My idea is to use table `loves` with following columns:

```
id - love id, primary_key
user_id - id of user who loves something, foreign_key
entity_type - type of entity which is loved by user, enum('image', 'video', 'post')
entity_id - id of entity which is loves (either image_id, video_id, post_id)

unique index on (user_id,entity_type,entity_id) -> user can love unique entity only once
```

In this solution I can't declare `foreign_key` on `loves.entity_id` because I dont know which table it refers to...

Is this a good approach?

Is there better solution than this?

I am using `postgres` but I tagged question with `mysql` because maybe is general problem in relational dbs?

Comment: `relational-database` and `database-design` are better tags than MySQL (because there are much more DBMS out there than just Postgres and MySQL) if you want a more "general" discussion

Comment: What you want is a de-nomarmalized schema. In some occasions is ok, but you need to be carefull. Imagin that your love object is pointing to an object that gets deleted. Your application have to control all this stuff (if can't find love object -> Love object = null)

Comment: I use this type of schema for instance to save addresses (with all is fields) for different objects on my database in a single table.

Comment: I don't see a reason to store also the entity_type unless you have an admin screen that shows all loves for a type.

Comment: @user2920788 Storing both the id and type allows you to backtrack and sanity check the id, the (id,type) pair is also needed to support the unique constraint.

Comment: What your trying to do is an [anti-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20873843/533120). Some alternatives are presnted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13317463/533120). You may  also be interested in [Implementing comments and Likes in database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8113064/533120).