# Which one is correct and optimized in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, relational-database, query-optimization

Imagine that I have three entities (`EntityA`, `EntityB`, `EntityC`) that can have some `images`. So there are two ways:

1. Make an `image` table for each entity. It means that `EntityA` has a `image` table named `AImages` and similarly for `EntityB` and `EntityC`.
   This method is more intelligent but has more tables.
2. Have an `image` table and another table name `EntityType` that goes between.

`EntityType` table has an `EntityTypeId` column and a `name` and has three records: `1,EntityA`, `2,EntityB`, `3,EntityC`.

Then in `image` table:

If I save a record for `EntityA` the record in `image` table would be this: `1,1,name`

First column is `ImageId`, second one is `EntityTypeId` and the third one is `image's filename`.

If I save a record for `EntityB` the record in `image` table would be this: `2,2,name`

And if I save a record for `EntityA` the record in `image` table would be this: `3,3,name`

In this method the number of tables would decrease but the queries would be longer.

Which one is optimised or any other way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have an image table and another table name EntityType that goes between.

This will require you to enforce the referential integrity manually, which is [trickier than it looks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20873843/533120).

So either:

- for each 1:N relationship, have a separate "N" table for each "1" table (as you proposed),
- or employ something like [exclusive FK or inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317463/533120) if you want to avoid too much structural duplication.

Answer (score 0):

The raght way is to store images in `varbinary(max)` columns in their respective tables, and not to separate them. SQL Server will take care of phisically storing them in an efficient, off-row, manner.

Depending on which version of SQL Server is used and the size of the LOBs, you might consider `FILESTREAM` or `FILETABLE` [feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx).

Comment: I am working on a web application. Is it optimize to save a file in database? So what about space managing or server resources managing or query sizes? And each record of entities can have any number of images.

Comment: If it's 1:m relationship, go the separate tables route (one image table for one regular). Consider the filestream anyway (there is a link in the answer to the docs on the feature).

Answer (score 0):

It seems having an `BaseEntity` table, that contains shared properties of other entities, will help you.
EntityA & EntityB & EntityC will be childes of the BaseEntity, their primary key will be the primary key of EntityBase table.
 A zero-or-one relation between them will do.
Having a discriminator column called entyty_type in BaseEntity will be recommanded.
Other collections like Images and adresses and else will be connected to this `EntityBase` table.
[image]