# Is indexes slow if I want to use foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I want to use foreign but I should add index.I heard that indexes is slow for inserting,this is really big issue because table's role which I need add foreign key , has a lot of update,insert,delete.Should I use foregn key?I dont want to slow down my query

Comment: i think you are over engineering,load test and see what is the performance,if it is not acceptable,then you can think of tuning..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An index on a foreign key is used when:

- parent row is about to be deleted,
- parent's key (which is referenced by the foreign key) is about to be modified.

*(It is **not** used when inserting or updating non-referenced fields of parent, nor when inserting, updating or deleting child.)*

And of course, queries (especially JOINs) "on top" of foreign keys are quite common, and they *may* benefit from such indexes too.

So, as a rule of thumb, if you do the above operations often, consider having an index on the foreign key. And since every index requires [maintenance](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/dml/insert), measure whether the price of maintenance justifies the speedup you get on these operations (as a rule of thumb, it usually does).

Comment: Can I use a lot foregn key for different tables(for each of them only 2 index one of them foregn)?For example I have posts table and there are image_id and user_id which is depend on other tables Should I give them foreign key?(My post table has a lot of select,insert and few update )

Comment: Yes. You should use FKs everywhere it is logical to do so. In fact, avoiding FKs for "performance" is usually a [very bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20873843/533120) - you'll typically end-up losing *both* integrity and performance. And for whether these FKs need to be indexed, see above. ;)

Answer (score 0):

let me explain what the actual whole concept of SQL Indexing and References

- Indexing is same as normal indexing in our books when we are looking for particular page/content/topic rather than referring one by one page we see in index and figure out the address of it.
- references is use to maintain the relationship between particular table or column
- how SQL exactly working when you are performing any operation [excluding Insertion] they are first going to search those data. first it will check in index[if available] else searching for data one by one row.
- so if you have an indexing you can make all the operation faster[ you have to make indexing of the those column on base you are performing most of operation like an ID,..]
  -in case of relationship you can also maintain in your code[only choose this option when you have an deep understanding of database and its flow]

**Suggession**  must use indexing [on only one field] and yes use relation as per your need it will never going to down your performance

Comment: But when I create table for examle posts table and there are post id (primary key) and also user_id and both of them should have Index because primary key itself is index and also I shoult=d use another index for user_id because it is foreign key.How can I use only one Index?

Comment: i mean one index per table and for foreign key you haven't need to apply indexing because its directly refer to primary key [ if you havent need of indexing on primary key you can also prevent them to be primary key]

Comment: But in my example I need primary key because post id should be autoincrement

Comment: do you make primary key just for auto increment? you can also make it auto increment without applying primary key.

Comment: Yes I know but if I do it posts id can be duplicate and primary key prevent it

Comment: But again if I use unique key it means that I have again 2 INDEX and also in this example post_id cant be null and it isnot nonclustered that why I should use primary key.How can I handle with it?