# SQL child with multiple 1-to-1 parents

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have 3 tables:

```
Plane (ID, Name)        //Parent
Car(ID, Name)           //Parent
Engine(ID, Name)        //Child
```

`Engine` table must have a parent which is either `Plane` or  `Car`. These tables are related with 1-to-1 relationship.

The main thing is that there is a need to get a parent through engine. How to correctly setup a database here?

---

I see multiple scenarios here but cannot figure out which is the best one:

1. Put `engine ID` at `Plane` and `Car`.  The problem I am facing here is that before I query I need to know which parent engine belongs to.
2. Have `plane_engine` and `car_engine` tables. Same problem as above + more overhead with separate tables which are more required for many-to-many relationship (which is not a case here)
3. Have a soft key and type at engine table (Parent_ID, Type). Problem which is at 1 and 2 scenarios is reduced but I cannot ensure that Type and Parent_ID will be true and represent what it should (f.e. Type is Car but Parent ID is of plane).

Any insights would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure, what's wrong with scenario #2? Anyway you need to know which one (or both) of `Car` and `Plane` is  relevant to the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Put engine ID at Plane and Car. The problem I am facing here is that before I query I need to know which parent engine belongs to.

This models N:1 between `Car` and `Engine` (and between `Plane` and `Engine`).

You'll need to make the `Car.EngineID` UNIQUE to have 0..1:1 (0 because this still allows a car-less engine). Otherwise, this looks fine for your stated requirement, and the index on `Car.EngineID` should ensure good performance when getting car(s) that correspond to a known engine.

> 2. Have plane_engine and car_engine tables. Same problem as above + more overhead with separate tables which are more required for many-to-many relationship (which is not a case here)

This models N:N as you rightfully noted.

It can be restricted to 0..1:N or N:0..1 or even 0..1:0..1 by making appropriate fields UNIQUE, but is generally unnecessary if you don't actually need N:N.

> 3. Have a soft key and type at engine table (Parent_ID, Type). Problem which is at 1 and 2 scenarios is reduced but I cannot ensure that Type and Parent_ID will be true and represent what it should (f.e. Type is Car but Parent ID is of plane).

This actually models 1:N between `Car` and `Engine` (and `Plane` and `Engine`). And as you noted it doesn't allow [proper enforcement of foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20873843/533120).

If 1:N is what you actually need, you can simply put...

```
PlaneID REFERENCES Plane
CarID REFERENCES Car
```

...in the `Engine`. And you can enforce the exclusivity (so the same engine cannot be user for car and plane)...

```
CHECK (
    (PlaneID IS NOT NULL AND CarID IS NULL)
    OR (PlaneID IS NULL AND CarID IS NOT NULL)
)
```

On the other hand, if you need 1:0..1 between `Car` and `Engine`, then just put a UNIQUE constraint on `Engine.CarID`. Ditto for planes.

Or you can use [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317463/533120).